# NSDateFormatter is not working with iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode7, nsdateformatter

I developed an app before one month at that time it is working fine but now i am going to change some `dates` but it returning `nil`

```
 NSDateFormatter *formatter2 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter2 setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"];
    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[NSDate date]];
    NSDate *changeDate2=[formatter2 dateFromString:str];
```

this code which was working . but now `changeDate2` is `nil` .

Comment: I can assure you it's working perfectly..

Comment: It is not working thats why i am post here. try in your Xcode 7.3.. it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need use your `NSDateFormatter` for convert [NSDate date] to string. Modify your code to below

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter2 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter2 setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"];
NSString *str = [formatter2 stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSDate *changeDate2=[formatter2 dateFromString:str];
```

Comment: NSDate *datStartDate = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    datStartDate = [dateFormatter  dateFromString:@"2016-10-01"];

this date also nil now

Comment: For case in your comment your dateFormatter need have a right dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd"

Comment: So what's the point of calling `stringFromDate:` and then `dateFromString:`?

Comment: `stringFromDate` will return `NSString` instance from specific date. `dateFromString` will return `NSDate` instance from specific string. but  `NSDateFormatter ` need have a common DateFormate for right convert